# MYSQL FOREIGN KEY ISSUES

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table which references two other tables that I have planned to make, but have not made yet. I am wondering if that is the issue here or if there is a syntax error that I am missing. If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated

> mysql> CREATE TABLE items (
> items$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> sales$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> img$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY(items$id),
> FOREIGN KEY(sales$id) REFERENCES sales(sales$id),
> FOREIGN KEY(img$id) REFERENCES image(img$id)
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY(items$id),
> FOREIGN KEY(sales$id) REFEREN' at line 6

I tried to remove the references, as in just do 'FOREIGN KEY(sales$id)' and 'FOREIGN KEY(img$id)' to see if that would work (I am new to mysql), but that also did not work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Only 1 auto_increment column is allowed and it must be the primary key or the first node of a compound key, Your referenced tables need to be created first with appropriate indexes https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and I don't much like the use of currency symbols in column names even if they are permitted.

Comment: And desc is a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your field name: `desc`

`desc` is a keyword in mysql see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_desc.asp)

Your sql would be better like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items ( items$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, sales$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, img$id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, descr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(items$id),
FOREIGN KEY(sales$id) REFERENCES sales(sales$id),
FOREIGN KEY(img$id) REFERENCES image(img$id))
```

Ps: you missed closing bracket ')' at the end of your sql query.